# Using useEffect for listening to state changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, react-component

I have the following useEffect hook:

```
useEffect(() => {
    let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    if (canvas && image.img) {
      let context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      //Redraw image
      context.drawImage(image.img, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);
      let scalePoint1 = retrievePointByName(drawnPoints, 'S1');
      let scalePoint2 = retrievePointByName(drawnPoints, 'S2');
      if (scalePoint1 && scalePoint2) {
        let scaleLine = new Line(scalePoint1, scalePoint2, null, 'ScalePoint');
        setScaleProperties({
          scaleDistance: scaleLine.length(), //What is the distance between the scale points (in pixels)
          scaleValueMm: scaleProperties.scaleValueMm, //How many mm-s does the specified distance corresponds to
          scaleFactor:
            scaleProperties.scaleDistance / scaleProperties.scaleValueMm, //scaleDistance/scaleValueMm. Gives the factor, how many pixels are equal to 1 mm.
        });
        scaleLine.draw();
      }
      drawnPoints.forEach((point) => {
        point.draw();
      });
      setDrawnLines([]);
      setWrongPointPlacement({
        lines: [],
      });
    }
  }, [drawnPoints]);
```

However, I get the following warning:

"React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'image.height', 'image.img', 'image.width', 'scaleProperties.scaleDistance', and 'scaleProperties.scaleValueMm'. Either include them or remove the dependency array."

Image and scaleProperties are also state variables of the component (defined with useState)

I feel like I'm potentially abusing useEffect. What I thought was using it as a listener for changes on the "drawnPoints" state, so that when the points are updated or changed, i re-draw the canvas. (And update some other dependent state) I'm working on some visualisation task.

If I'm indeed misusing this concept, then what is the "accepted" or "best-practice" way for achieving this in react?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `useEffect` usage rule says that whenever you use a `variable` that was defined outside the `useEffect` hook then you must add it to the `dependency array` because `useEffect` is depending on it and listening to its changes and whenever their values change it'll have to `re-run`.

In your case let's consider this line of code:

```
  //Redraw image
  context.drawImage(image.img, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);
```

The reason why you're getting this warning is that on the line where you're `redrawing` the circle, you told `useEffect` to always redraw the image whenever `image.height,image.img,image.width` change. The reason for this as I said is because `image.height,image.img,image.width` were defined outside the `useEffect` hook.

Comment: I see. "because useEffect is depending on it and listening to its changes and whenever their values change it'll have to rerender" - This means, actually the use-effect dependency array is not used to define what triggers the re-render but rather the re-rendering always happen, but what is in the array is checked for changes right?

Comment: Exactly. If the array is left empty then the useEffect will be run only when the component gets mounted, but when you add values you mean that the useEffect will be run when the component is rendered and also when the values in the array change.